# Black Screen on simulator Xcode 9

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode9, sigabrt

When I run my simulator it turns to a black screen for only that app. I have tried many things, for an example: Erase All Content and Setting. Nothing works, and I also get Thread 1: signal SIGABRT message when I click the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run command:

```
defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferRendererHint 3
```

Close simulator if opened. Again re-open and run the app. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

When using Swift with XCode, the Thread 1: SIGABRT error can also be thrown during build and test if you deleted an object, such as a button or a text box.  You must also delete the dependencies for that object. Open the utilities tab, select the connections inspector and ensure that none of the connections have an exclamation point, indicating a connection that is invalid.[example of the invalid connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr2s8.png)